# How can I generate an HTTPS URL from binary data?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have some binary data, how can I generate an HTTP or HTTPS URL containing the binary data using JavaScript so that the binary data can be downloaded as a file from the URL? I'm trying to be able to generate files to download on the Amazon Kindle Paperwhite, but it has said it can only download files using an HTTP or HTTPS protocol.

Comment: You do understand binary is just 8 bits equaling a byte of 0s or 1s. You just need to convert, the text is essentially binary-based off the ASCII table.

Comment: @Raymond he's talking about encoding the data of a binary file into the URL, similar to what you can do using the `data:` scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. The longer answer is that the `http:` or `https:` part of the URL defines the URI scheme, which tell the client what it should do with the following text. In the case of `http:` or `https:` the client knows that whatever comes after that is a location of a resource on the internet and it will use HTTP or HTTPS to establish a connection to the host and request the specified resource. If you pass it something other than a location of a resource it will simply fail when it tries to establish that connection.

There's a list of possible schemes here, which should give you some context as to what the schemes mean and why they can't be swapped and changed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes